# Nginx and rails configuration for CORS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

What is the best way to configure nginx and Rails app for CORS?

All configuration in the nginx file(option 1)

```
server {
    listen 5500;
    server_name someserver;
    root /opt/current/public;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://anotherserver;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers '*';
}
```

All configurations in the config/application.rb file(option 2)

```
  config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins  'anotherserver'
      resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options, :patch, :delete]
    end
  end
```

Option 3 is to add both configurations

All 3 options has its problems because I have some assests files served by nginx and the there are other REST calls. With option 1 the regular rest calls are not working. With option 2 only the assets files are not loaded and with option 3 it complains that the origin is set twice.

Comment: Or you can route your API calls via nginx, and set the headers only at nginx side.

Comment: I have fixed the issue by adding a location directive only for static assets and setting the origin header for that.